# Google Public DNS- private enough?

Tags: privacy

Google claims that they do not keep any personally identifiable information but they do keep a user's ISP and geo-location information including the geocode, as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/privacy?hl=en).

To keep the question objective: Isn't geocode and ISP combination likely to be personally identifying, specially if one lives in a house?

Answer (score 2):

*geocode* is not always precise and personally, for the cases I faced, it has never been that precise (see the `location_type` parameter in [The Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro))

Also, from the link you provided, it says:

> We don't correlate or combine information from our temporary or
>   permanent logs with any personal information that you have provided
>   Google for other services.

And the permanent samples Google collects are done randomly. Also, there are not lot of ISP providers per country (check the case of [France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Internet_service_providers_of_France), for example) so it is hard to use that to identify a particular person.

To conclude, if we trust the official documentation you linked to, I do not see any serious privacy concern in that.

Comment: the important information that is missing in that official documentation is the user's public IP. If an ISP is providing static Public IP addresses then the user's public IP could be used to identify a particular connection. so I agree with you.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I should note that @munchkin's point is very relevant too.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, the street view car has been known to slurp all wifi traffic along the way and correlate the mac address with the physical address. That way you go from dns->ip->mac->geodata.

Edit:  And by dns,  i mean the query and answer segment.

Comment: Except the MAC address doesn't correlate with the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

No it definitely isn't enough to identify you personally. The location one can collect from an IP-Address isn't very specific. You might be able to point the location of a client down to a radius of between 20km to 50km which clearly can't be used to identify a person. To do this you can use a Geo IP Database which assigns specific networks to a specific Area.